# In CRM 2011 SQL Timeout/Locking issue when processing AssociateRequest

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a plugin that I want to run synchronously as a Post Process because if any of the requests it makes fail I'd like to roll everything back in one transaction.  I've encountered an issue where if I try to run an AssociateRequest to associate another record to the record that triggered the plugin it returns a SQL timeout.  I know that my code is correct because I'm using the same code to associate other records (that aren't firing the plugin) and they execute fine.

```
        var referencedEntityRelationship = new Relationship(ReferencedEntityRelationshipName);
        var referencedEntityEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection(new EntityReference[] { new EntityReference(ReferencedEntityLogicalName, new Guid(receivedRequest.ReferencingEntityId)) });
        var rtn = new AssociateRequest() { RelatedEntities = referencedEntityEntities, Relationship = referencedEntityRelationship };
        rtn.Target = new EntityReference() { Id = responseId, LogicalName = dataEntityLogicalName };
```

I know I can avoid the lock by running the plugin asynchronously.  But if there is a failure for some reason I'm unable to roll back the initial request that fired the plugin and notify the user that they need to fix something.  Any advice on how to execute associate requests within a plugin against the record that fired the plugin are appreciated.

Comment: Which rollup are you on? I've dealt with similar issues before, some of this was resolved around rollup 16 - 18 (I don't remember which had which sql changes.)

Comment: Rollup 16.  I'll review some of the rollups.

Comment: Rollup 16 (which they have) says "SQL Deadlocks when calling Associate request adding users to teams. "  I didn't find anything about associate requests or deadlocks in later rollups.  Good idea though.  For now I've had to just use async plugins, but it's a really bad solution for this particular need.  Any advice on how you've dealt with it before would be great.

Comment: I want to say there may have been some other SQL changes in 17 or 18 - not sure if they were documented as such. That said, if they are one-to-many then I just used the `Update` method to set the foreign key on the appropriate record - don't think I had an issue doing that. I can't remember if I ever had this issue for a many-to-many. If you do a trace on the server you can track down the specific call generating the timeout. Is it saying SQL Timeout or Generic SQL Error - Generic SQL Error would be more inline with what I've seen w/ deadlocks.